# JavaScript delete elements in array by a criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, and I want to delete elements that have status equal to true (as seen in this part of code)

```
listArray.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element.status === true) {
            listArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that, if, for example, the `first`, `second` and `third` elements have status `true`, than the second element will not be deleted

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: So what you want is to [*filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array?

Comment: Yes because you modify your array at same time you walk throught it

Comment: Use `listArray.filter( e => !e.status);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
listArray.filter(element => element.status === false)
```

You can also do:

```
listArray.filter(element => !element.status)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
listArray = listArray.filter(element => !element.status);
```

Comment: This does not filter the array. Instead returns a boolean array.

Comment: wrong keyword, I admit